# Using pushState inside success function of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate

I want to append one more param at the end of the current url if the ajax call returns successfully. In this context, we can get back the identifier of the object has been persisted into the database, then append this identifier to the url.

The problem is `curationNotes` of `data` was lost if the line `window.history.pushState({}, null, newHref);` is uncommented. It means we cannot get 'params.curationNotes' in controller. The `params.curationNotes`, which is a map of user provided values on the form, is `null` when we try to parse it inside the controller.

Below is the snippet I am working on.

```
$('#btnSave').on("click", function(event) {
if ($('#curationNotesForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
    var curationNotes = buildCurationNotesTC();
    "use strict";
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        url: $.jummp.createLink("curationNotes", "doAddOrUpdate"),
        cache: true,
        data: {
            curationNotes: curationNotes,
            model: "${id}"
        },
        processData: true,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#txtStatus').text("The curation notes are being saved. Please wait...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            var href = window.location.href;
            if (href.indexOf("&cnId=") < 0) {
                var newHref = href + "&cnId=" + response['cnId'];
                //window.history.pushState({}, null, newHref);
            }
            $('#txtStatus').text(response['message']);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // TODO: the error message doesn't show properly
            $('#txtStatus').text("Error: ", jqXHR.responseText + textStatus + errorThrown + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }
    });
} else {
    $('#txtStatus').text("Please check required fields and click Save button again...");
}
});
```

If I comment this line `window.history.pushState({}, null, newHref);`, the code is working properly.

Notes: this snippet works fine in any web browsers on Linux but cannot work in any web browser of Windows 10. That's actually ridiculous to me.

Have you ever had any experience with this problem?

Comment: While this code expresses how you are updating the state and submitting a form, your question requests to know why the data is unavailable to the controller. Please reduce your example to the most simple reproducible code and update your question.

Comment: That's weird but you have some mistakes. `dataType: "text"` is suspicious for one thing. More importantly: the default value is `undefined` _not_ `null`. Also, please indicate which browsers you've tried on Windows 10 and also on Linux

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: On Linux Redhat 6 workstation, I test with Firefox and Chromium while  the latest Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10